# Isogenies in multidimensional formal groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, formal-groups

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a local field, $A$ the ring of integers of K, $\pi$ a uniformizer element for $A$, $F$ an n-dimensional formal group with coefficients in $A$ and $f$ an endomorphism of $F$. When we look at the reduction of $f$ $\pmod \pi$ it has the form $t(x^{p^h})$, where $X^{p^h}=(X_1^{p^h},\dots, X_N^{p^h})$ and the matrix, C(t), of linear coefficients of $t$ is not the zero matrix.

Do you know a proof-or a reference where I can look at- of the following theorem?

Theorem1:$f$ is an isogeny(i.e surjective and finite kernel) iff $c(t)$ is invertible. And the kernel is a porwer of $p$.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Take a look at M. Hazewinkel's Formal Groups and Applications. I think you'll find a proof or (at least) an idea of how you can prove the theorem.

Comment: Example (at $p=2$): Take the self-map of $\widehat{\Bbb G}_m \times \widehat{\Bbb G}_m$ given by multiplication by $2$ on the first factor and the identity on the second factor.  Then $h=0$, and the matrix $C(t)$ is rank one, but the kernel is $\mu_2 \times \{1\}$.